# Cannot resolve method overridePendingTransition in android studio

Tags: android

I cannot use *overridePendingTransition* method in my code to call activity transition inside **onClick()** method. I used *((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);* but it is not working as well. Please help me.

My source code:

```
holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,New_Activity.class);

                intent.putExtra("Name",album.getName());

                intent.putExtra("Songs",album.getNumOfSongs());
                intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",album.getThumbnail());

                mContext.startActivity(intent);

              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full adapter code? It'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

Comment: Where did you get context?

Comment: Context context;

In onCreateView you can do context = parent.getContext();

Comment: Please add an explanation.